# Navigation from the login page after the user logged in

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, authentication

this is my code for the login page. but there is no 'navigation' coded after the user logged in. Need some help to code this.( Navigation code to navigate to the next form)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=chariths-bently\\charith;Initial Catalog=emp_mgt;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
            }
        }

        private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ok(username.Text, password.Text) > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Access granted");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("access denied");
        }

        private int ok( string username, string password)
        {
            username.Trim();
            password.Trim();
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            using(SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=chariths-bently\\charith;Initial Catalog=emp_mgt;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                myconnection.Open();
                string query = "select * from emp_info ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,myconnection);
                if(cmd.ExecuteScalar () != null)                    
                   return 1;
                else
                   return 0;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you minimize the code to what's relevant and/or describe what you are expecting? you will probably get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ok(username.Text, password.Text) > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Access granted");
        Form6 f6 = new Form6(); // create your next form instance,(form6, for example)
        f6.Open();
        this.Close();
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: thank you it works. also can i know how to set the different navigations from the log in form, based on user level - for example if admin logged in he is directed to admin form and if employee logged in he is directed to employee form